# Instalar um aplicativo

Tags: c#

Qual é a melhor maneira e a mais simples de criar um instalador customizável em C#?

Ex arquivos:

```
\bin32\dedicated.exe
\bin32\server.exe
\bin32\sdk.exe
\etc\lib.def
\etc\resume32.def
```

Fazer com que o aplicativo faça a instalação por exemplo desses arquivos para uma pasta selecionada, mostrando progresso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para fazer um diálogo com uma `ProgressBar` faça o seguinte:

Inicie uma classe com o nome que quiser, exemplo:

```
public class ProgressoDeInstalacao : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{ /* ... */ }
```

Declare essa variável com todos os arquivos que quiser instalar:

```
string[] ArquivosParaInstalar = [@"\bin32\dedicated.exe", @"\bin32\sdk.exe", @"\etc\lib.def", @"\etc\resume32.def"];
```

Coloque isso no método construtor:

```
public ProgressoDeInstalacao()
{
  //até ai OK, crie uma variável com o total de itens:
  Int32 TotalDeItens = ArquivosParaInstalar.Count();

  //Suponha que você tem sua ProgressBar dentro dum diálogo, vamos chamar-la de "Processo"
  Processo.MaxValue = TotalDeItens; //altera o total de itens
  Processo.Value    = 0;            //reseta o valor dela

  this.Update(); //atualiza
}
```

Agora vamos criar um método chamado `InstallFile` onde vai instalar o arquivo:

```
 void InstallFile(string Arquivo)
 {
     System.IO.File.Copy(Arquivo, @"C:\Arquivos de programas\<nome do seu app>\" + IO.Path.GetFilenameWithoutExtension(Arquivo) + IO.Path.GetExtension(Arquivo));
     /* Explicação:
        @"C:\Arquivos de programas\<nome do seu app>\" = é onde seus arquivos serão copiados
        IO.Path.GetFilenameWithoutExtension(Arquivo)   = é o nome do seu arquivo sem sua extensão e caminho
        IO.Path.GetExtension(Arquivo)                  = extensão do arquivo
      */ 
   }
```

agora o trabalhador:

```
   public void Trabalhar()
   {
      foreach (string arquivo in ArquivosParaInstalar)
      {
          Processo.Value += 1; //Aumenta o processo para 1 arquivo.
          Processo.Update();   //Opcional. É recomendado por isso para atualizar o ProgressBar.
          try {
             InstallFile(arquivo); //copia o arquivo para a pasta
          } catch ex { 
            System.Console.WriteLine(@"Erro: {0}", ex.Message) //Ocorreu um erro, no console vai mostrar por que.
          }
       }
    }
```

Agora quando for instalar o aplicativo, chame com essa simples linha:

```
     ProgressoDeInstalacao dialogo = new ProgressoDeInstalacao()
     dialogo.Trabalhar(); //irá começar o trabalho
```

Abraços, se não ajudar, comenta no post.

Answer (score 0):

Existe um software bem simples chamado [InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) que faz isso que você está pedindo. Ele basicamente permite que você crie um wizard customizável, escolhendo os arquivos que serão extraídos, bem como o executável do seu programa juntamente com uma tonelada de outras opções.

Comment: Então mas eu quero um aplicativo que eu possa personalizar ele do melhor jeito possível!